# how to get the name of visitor on my website if he is logged into hi facebook account without connecting my website to his facebook profile?

Tags: facebook

how to get the name of visitor on my website if he is logged into his *facebook* account without connecting my website to his facebook profile?

I want to show in header that You are logged in to `facebook` account as `fbusername` how can I do this? Plz answer

Answer (score 0):

You want to show his Facebook name on your site without having your site linked to Facebook ? Not possible, where will you get this data from ?